# How to Get Proper Count of Values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I tried asking this question earlier and miscommunicated what I am having trouble with. I have a dataset in python that I am using numpy and pandas in and I am trying to get a count of reports by job type. There are are 100+ titles so I will shorten it for an example:

```
 ID       Job_Title        reports  
 1        Sales Manager       2
 1        Sales Manager       2
 2        Tech Support        0
 3        Tech Support        1
 3        Tech Support        1
 4        Sales Lead          4
 4        Sales Lead          4
 5        Sales Manager       5
 6        Tech Support        2
```

I would like to get a accurate count of the reports by position. Something Like this:

```
 Job_Title      reports    
Sales Manager     7
Sales Lead        4
Tech Support      3
```

So far what I have is this:

```
 df.groupby('Job_Title')['reports'].count().sort_values(ascending = False)
```

And this is what I am getting:

```
Job_Title         reports
Tech Support         4
Sales Manager        3
Sales Lead           2
```

Comment: what is the logic? why do you have only 7 for Sales Manager?

Comment: 7 would be the actual amount 2 by ID 1  and 5 by ID 5 the rows aren't the total number of reports by ID are always shown

Comment: You have some duplicates

Comment: In the data their are dates and many other fields that show changes for the sake of time and space I didn't want to show it all

Comment: So drop duplicates by ID and JobTitle is the right option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected result, you have to drop duplicates by `ID` and `Job_Title` before grouping by `Job_Title` and sum `reports` values:

```
>>> (df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Job_Title'])
       .groupby('Job_Title', as_index=False)['reports'].sum()
       .sort_values(by='reports', ascending=False, ignore_index=True))

       Job_Title  reports
0  Sales Manager        7
1     Sales Lead        4
2   Tech Support        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df_new = (df.groupby('Job_Title', as_index=False)['reports'].apply(lambda g: sum(set(g))).sort_values('reports', ascending = False, ignore_index=True))
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
       Job_Title  reports
0  Sales Manager        7
1     Sales Lead        4
2   Tech Support        3
```